# Trouble with Typescript targeting scss style properties

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an IONIC 2 project in typescript. I have the following css:

```
.bottle {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, pink 100%, white 0%);
}
```

and I wanted to adjust the `pink` value on the linear-gradient,from Javascript / Typescript.I have already done the following in my typescript, but I got an error saying that the style element does not exist on bottleFill. What have I done wrong?

```
import {Page, Alert, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic.html'
})

export class HelloIonicPage {
    constructor(public nav: NavController) { }

    updateDisplay(batteryPercentage){
        var bottleFill = document.getElementsByClassName('bottle')[0];

        if(percentage <= 100){
            bottleFill.style.linerar-gradient.pink = batteryPercentage + '%';
            batteryPercentage += 5;
        }        
    }
}
```

## Update:

The full error:

> The property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

using ngOnInit to use the element selector didn't work...

Comment: Is bottleFill undefined? This code could be running before the element is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should retrieve the css in the ngAfterViewInit method which is called by Angular once views are initialized :
http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't help, I just get "bottleFill is not recognized", I'll update the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use **type assertion** to inform typescript that it is actually  HTMLElement:

```
var bottleFill = document.getElementsByClassName('bottle')[0] as HTMLElement;
```